# Sequence of random variables i.i.d. with normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I'm confused with this problem. I've seen this problem and I think is wrong. But if not, anyone please give me a hand. Thanks.

> Let $(\mathcal{X}_{i}) $ a sequence of random variables such that $ \mathcal{X}_{i} $ is distributed $N(1,3)$ for all $ i \in \mathbb{N} $. Show
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mathcal{X}_1+ \cdots + \mathcal{X}_n}{ \mathcal{X}_1^{2} + \cdots + \mathcal{X}_n^{2}} = \frac{1}{4}\right) = 1.$$

Comment: Are you aware of the strong law of large numbers?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee yes, multiplying by (1/n)  We obtained only the denominator no? Because all expected value of sequence is 1

Comment: I am not sure about your comment. Notice that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \mathbf{Var}(X_i) + \mathbb{E}[X_i]^2 = 3 + 1 = 4$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Sorry, i've said my comment because i think you said me use strong law of numbers. Multipliying by $\frac{1}{n}$   $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mathcal{X}_1+ \cdots + \mathcal{X}_n}{ n \mathcal{X}_1^{2} + \cdots + \mathcal{X}_n^{2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{1}{4n}$ And we have by the strong law of numbers $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{ \mathcal{X}_1^{2} + \cdots + \mathcal{X}_n^{2}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4n}$  but here i'm stuck

Comment: Multiply both numerator *and* denominator by $\ \frac{1}{n}\ $. This doesn't change the fraction, but as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $, the numerator divided by $\ n\ $ converges to $1$ almost surely, and the denominator divided by $\ n\ $ converges to $4$ almost surely.

Comment: @lonza leggiera you're right. I've done the exercise with the help of both. Thanks.